# How can I install Gimp 2.8's help documentation on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: installation, gimp, documentation, helpfile

Ubuntu 12.04 comes with Gimp 2.6, so I installed Gimp 2.8 using the instructions below:

> ```
> sudo apt-get purge gimp*  
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp  
> sudo apt-get update  
> sudo apt-get install gimp
> ```

When try to open help, I get the message below. How do I install and configure the help for 2.8 on Ubuntu?

[image: Dialog that says: "The GIMP user manual is not installed on your computer. You may either install the additional help package or change your preferences to use the online version". It has two buttons: "Cancel", and "Read Online".]

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, the PPA does not contain the required package for the documentation, or GIMP's documentation has not been made ready yet for 2.8.

In any case, try

```
apt-cache search gimp-help
```

and install the appropriate package for your language.

Comment: You are correct, [the PPA most certainly does not](https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/gimp/+sourcepub/2520960/+listing-archive-extra).

Comment: `sudo apt-get install gimp-help-en` installed the 2.6 version help and not 2.8. 2.8 help is available at ftp://ftp.gimp.org/pub/gimp/help/, but I am not sure how to integrate it with Gimp.

Comment: @PraveenSripati You might contact the PPA maintainer and ask if they can package the appropriate version of `gimp-help` as well. (They might not, but it's worth asking.) Also, the upcoming release of Ubuntu--Quantal--will have `gimp` 2.8. It's still in development and it still has `gimp-help` 2.6, but once that's updated Quantal is released, you could [request a backport](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuBackports).

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on it.

There are some some compiling issues.

Please wait.

Thorsten Stettin

https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch

It looks good.

Please wait for publishing on my Gimp PPA.

Answer (score 0):

Use Synaptic package manager (System/Administration/Synaptic Package Manager) and search gimp help in the search box. Mark the package of your language for installation and click apply. Give password when required.

I don't know why they haven't added help as default with the package as gimp is for advanced uses. Any way, enjoy :)

Comment: I recommend editing this to explain how to install and run Synaptic on Ubuntu 12.04, as there is not (or not obviously) any way to go to System > Administration in Unity, and Synaptic is not installed by default.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install gimp-8.2.6 from gimp website, and downloaded tar.bz2. Inside its install instructions, there are more requirements and some what complex. So i decided to install from package.

1. open terminal
2. sudo apt-get update *"This is to check the version all-ready available in software center."*
3. Open software center > search or go to gimp = check the version is latest(8.2.6) or not (It will be at, before the reviews/comments.)
4. If latest version intall.

OR

1. open terminal
2. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
3. sudo apt-get update
4. Open software center > go to gimp > check the version > install

IF ITS NOT THE LATEST VERSION ONLY YOU HAVE TO CHANGE THE REPOSITORY(2).

--
THIS INSTALL IS NEAT AND WORKS GOOD. IT HAS HELP TOO.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Documentation for the GIMP (English), from Ubuntu Apps, by clicking [**English Documentation** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gimp-help-en/).

You can check out [Ubuntu Apps](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/search/?q=gimp&op=) for more languages.